# Opposite block control sliding game

Tags: mazes, board-games

Here's a fun maze/grid puzzle inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47834/help-me-to-find-a-small-but-hard-and-clever-maze/47875#47875).

**Rules of play:**

Firstly, no two coins may occupy the same space at a time

Suppose we label the blue coins B1, B2

- Then if B1 is on an arrow then we are allowed to move B2 in that direction (and vice versa)
- If B1 is on a number we can move B2 that many squares **BUT** it may **NOT** go through another coin (say it can move 3 squares but the square directly above it is occupied, then it cannot move up)
- If B1 is on an empty square we not move B2
- Lastly, you are not allowed to go off the 4x4 grid.

**Aim:** Swap the red coins with the blue coins.

Here you go!

[image]

Comment: At the start, may the SE red coin move 2 squares in a zig-zag or must it go straight? Also, may it move another 2 squares immediately after moving 2?

Comment: In answer to the first question, it must move straight 2 squares. And for the second question, yes it may move twice or 3 times in a row.

Comment: Are solutions found by computer acceptable?

Comment: I guess a solution is a solution... :) But really, the puzzle is quite fun to do by hand (just use four counters or something)

Comment: Suppose a coin is not on the edge of the board, does this means that he can't do the "3 squares" movement at all?

Comment: @FrodCube Yep, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really liked this puzzle, as it was easy to reproduce on paper and posed a real challenge. Solving with trial and error did not work.

I've recorded the solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYZRfNfIYhs

Thanks for the puzzle!

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to include an explanation of the solution. Link-only answers are discouraged here, because if the link goes dead (and Youtube links go dead all the time), then the answer would be rendered useless.